# How do I keep example code in my SPM project from importing into Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a Framework project on GitHub that includes sample code. How do I set up the Package.swift file or project so Xcode doesn't import the `Sample Apps` folder?

GitHub project: `https://github.com/AaronBratcher/AgileDB`

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, there is no way to keep it from downloading the entire hierarchy of files.